# CakePHP2 how to check referral URL only when POST

Tags: cakephp

I'm using CakePHP2 (2.6.3) and I need to check referral URL when POST action for avoiding some security issues.
In CakePHP 1.x days, there used to be configuration `Security.level` which can be set to check if referral URL is sort of the same domain, but it seems have been removed.

How to check referral URL only when POST?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use security component of cakephp. 
It can add csrf token to post call. I think its something that you need.
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/security-component.html
Otherwise you can check manually for $this->referer()

```
public function beforeFilter(){
   if($this->request->is('post')){
        //check for referal
   }
   parent::beforeFilter();
}
```

Comment: Thank you. First I considered using security component, but it requires form helpers. We already have quite a few forms created without form helpers... I think I should go manual checking.